# Problem when calling identical javascript for calendar plugin

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a calendar app to connect multiple different calendars. The way they show the calendar is not really suitable for me so I've been trying to change the JavaScript but as soon as I try to call another version, even if it is exactly the same the calendar don't show, so is there some way to use my own JavaScript? I've tried contacting the creator of the app but no luck.

Working code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://panel.bed-booking.com/widget/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://panel.bed-booking.com/widget/main_full.js?ver=20180768'></script>
<div id='bb-calendar-0'>
  <center>
    <img style='width:50px !important; height:50px !important;' src='https://panel.bed-booking.com/widget/gfx/loader.gif' alt='' /><br/>
    <a href='http://bed-booking.com' style='color:#73b819 !important' rel='nofollow'>BedBooking</a>
  </center>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  new CalendarFull(
    '0097661bc090e1ca78b844285df5a9c1',
    '0',
    'bb-calendar-0',
    {
      normal: '7dbb2c',
      reserved: 'fb1643',
      nextMonth: 'ecf5e1',
      font:'81817f',
      width: 450,
      lang: 'en',
      showBBLink: 'none'
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Test code with javascript at http://yourjavascript.com/31631229421/main-full.js

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://panel.bed-booking.com/widget/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://yourjavascript.com/31631229421/main-full.js'></script>
<div id='bb-calendar-0'>
  <center>
    <img style='width:50px !important; height:50px !important;' src='https://panel.bed-booking.com/widget/gfx/loader.gif' alt='' /><br/>
    <a href='http://bed-booking.com' style='color:#73b819 !important' rel='nofollow'>BedBooking</a>
  </center>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  new CalendarFull(
    '0097661bc090e1ca78b844285df5a9c1',
    '0',
    'bb-calendar-0',
    {
      normal: '7dbb2c',
      reserved: 'fb1643',
      nextMonth: 'ecf5e1',
      font:'81817f',
      width: 450,
      lang: 'en',
      showBBLink: 'none'
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0gk6L9pr/

test fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xq1t6ujv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time, please make your code more readable, one giant blob of code doesn't help anyone (especially yourself, because you are the one that has to work with it).

The error is in the link you provided, because it doesn't contain anything? Just compare these two:

- http://yourjavascript.com/64351117249/main-full.js
- https://panel.bed-booking.com/widget/main_full.js?ver=20180768

One is completely empty and the other actually has something you can use.